# buffer written twice to file

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to save some data in a simple text file using C.
The problem is that when I write the buffer into the file it is written two times.
I cant figure out why.  I tried with fwrite and fputs; same problem, any help is welcome.

```
void addEdge(graph_t *graph, int src, int dest)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("C:\\graph.txt", "a");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char  *c1 =malloc(8* sizeof(char *)),c2[2]="\0";
    itoa(src, c1, 10);
    itoa(dest, c2, 10);
    /* print some text */
    char text[2] = "::";
    strcat(c1,text);
    printf("c1 before %s \n",c1);
    strcat(c2,"\0");
    strcat(c1,c2);
    printf("c1 after %s ++++++++ c2  %s \n",c1,c2);

    //fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
    //fprintf(f, "%s \n", c1);
    ///fputs(c1,f);
    char* pos;
    pos = strchr(c1, '\0');
    int index = (int)(pos - c1);
    fwrite (c1 , sizeof(char), index , f);
    fclose(f);
/**************** some other stuff */
}
```

The execution of this code should give me this for var `src` = 2 and `dest` = 18

```
2::8
```

but in the file I get this

```
2::1818
```

Comment: I wonder what you're doing with the "\0"'s in your code. What are they in there for? For example with strcat. Either the string already has a null terminating character or it doesn't. If you try to strcat another \0 onto the end, strcat first has to find the \0 at the end and then --- add another one? Why?

Comment: And using strchr to find \0 is exactly the same as using strlen. Is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fopen with the mode "a" means to append.  This means if your file contains any previous data, that will remain and anything you write will be appended to the end.  Are you sure that this is not your problem?  Try using "w" to replace old contents.

Comment: that was the solution i changed the mode to a+ and used the code from above to simplify :D thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot more code there than really necessary.  Try this instead:

```
void addEdge(graph_t *graph, int src, int dest)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("C:\\graph.txt", "a");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(f, "%d::%d", src, dst);     /* <== much simpler, no? */
    fclose(f);
/**************** some other stuff */
}
```

Comment: thanks I tried it but i still have the same problem..
output :
2::1717 
5::1414 
9::1010

Answer (score 0):

```
void addEdge(graph_t *graph, int src, int dest)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("C:\\graph.txt", "a");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char  *c1 =malloc(8* sizeof(char *)),c2[2]="\0";
```

The line above attempts to allocate 8 bytes to c1.  If malloc() fails, it will return NULL.  The following line attempts to write to the allocated memory, resulting in a "NULL pointer assignment" runtime error.

```
    itoa(src, c1, 10);
```

The line above is not safe. The string generated by itoa() may have a length of up to 33 bytes (including the optional sign and the terminating sting terminator).  The allocated block of memory pointed to by c1 is only 8 bytes.  Worst case, itoa() may right beyond the memory allocated, overwriting adjacent memory.

```
    itoa(dest, c2, 10);
```

The line above is even more unsafe; where the array c2[] is only two bytes.

```
    /* print some text */
    char text[2] = "::";
```

The above line is bad code.  The string "::" equates to {':', ':', '\0'} which is three bytes.  The char array 'text' is only two bytes.  Likely, this will result in writing beyond the end of the 'text' string by one byte; resulting in over-writing adjacent memory.

```
    strcat(c1,text);
```

Being that the string placed into c1 may already be larger than the space allocated, the above line is just as dangerous.  Given that the variable text might not be properly terminated (given that the string terminator lies outside the space allocated).

```
    printf("c1 before %s \n",c1);
    strcat(c2,"\0");
```

The above line does nothing useful.  The string in array c2[2] has already overflowed the memory allocated.

```
    strcat(c1,c2);
```

The above line appends the (overflowed) array c2 value to the end of c1.

```
    printf("c1 after %s ++++++++ c2  %s \n",c1,c2);

    //fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
    //fprintf(f, "%s \n", c1);
    ///fputs(c1,f);
    char* pos;
    pos = strchr(c1, '\0');
    int index = (int)(pos - c1);
    fwrite (c1 , sizeof(char), index , f);
    fclose(f);
/**************** some other stuff */
}
```

---

Not knowing the exact goal, here is an attempt at a re-write:

```
void addEdge(graph_t *graph, int src, int dest)
   {
   FILE *f = NULL;

   errno=0;                           /* Requires the header 'errno.h' */
   f = fopen("C:\\graph.txt", "a");
   if(NULL == f)
        {
        printf("Error opening file!  errno[%d]\n", errno);
        exit(1);
        }

   /* print some text */
   fprintf(f, "%d::%d", dest, src);
   fclose(f);
/**************** some other stuff */
}
```